# Term premium with daily vs monthly time series

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, bond-yields, term-structure

I have estimated the term premium for the Polish Government Bonds (POLGBs) using the methods described by [Adrian et al. (2013)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304405X13001335) (often referred to as ACM). The underlying yields are interpolated from the Nelson-Siegel-Svensson model based on a bootstrapped zero-coupon yield curve.

I have estimated the model for two time series:

**1. Daily 10Y POLGBs Yields from 24/01/2005 to 20/05/2022**

[image]
**2. Monthly 10Y POLGBs Yields from the last day of each calendar month from 24/01/2005 to 20/05/2022**
[image]

Although the monthly yields are subsetted from the daily yields, the picture painted by each term-premium estimate is drastically different, especially during the 2020-2021 quantitative easing program from the Polish Central Bank. The monthly term-premium would have similar dynamics to the [analogous term-premium estimates for the German BUNDs](https://www.research.unicredit.eu/DocsKey/fxfistrategy_docs_2019_175097.ashx?EXT=pdf&KEY=KZGTuQCn4lsvclJnUgseVEGHysWJl2NsalH1w8p3dPurdMMtjayMTw==&T=1#:%7E:text=The%20ACM%20model%20explained,rolling%20over%20short%2Dmaturity%20bonds.). Which estimate would you find more reliable?

Comment: At a glance the monthly version is far more sensible. The preferred approach is to estimate the model using monthly data, then apply the parameters to daily data.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Helin. Just to make sure I have got the procedure right - I should estimate the A and B' for the selected maturities on monthly data, then re-run the PCA on the daily yields and construct fitted yields using the factors of daily yields?

Comment: @Helin I would assume that a model estimated this way for daily data would have a fit drastically worse than the monthly model. Am I correct?